# Reference request: Zero set of global section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Things are in the complex algebraic setting.

Assume that a vector bundle $V$ of rank $n$ over a $\mathbb{P}^n$ has a global section $\sigma$. Is it true that the zero set of $\sigma$ is a $0$-dimensional subscheme of length $c_n(V)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens if you take zero sets of global sections of $\mathcal O(1)$?

Comment: As @AriyanJavanpeykar indicates, unless $r=n$ the question doesn't seem to make sense. Did you mean to ask about that case?

Comment: Oh yes, I have edited it.

Comment: What if you take $(f,\ldots,f)\in \oplus_{i=1}^n\Gamma(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal O(1)) \subset \Gamma(\mathbb P^n,\mathcal O(1)^{\oplus n})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(collecting comments into an answer...)

As @Ariyan's comment points out, there is no reason in general that the zero set $Z(\sigma)$ should have the right dimension. For example, if $V = \mathcal{O}(1)^{\oplus n}$, and $f \in \Gamma \mathcal{O}(1)$ is a nonzero section, then the section $(f,\ldots,f) \in \Gamma(V)$ vanishes exactly along $Z(f)$, a subset of codimension 1 rather than $n$.

On the other hand, if you *assume* that $Z(\sigma)$ is zero-dimensional, then yes, it will be a subscheme of length $c_n(V)$. Fulton's *Intersection Theory* is the standard reference for these kinds of things; for this specific question there is surely a much simpler reference, but I don't know one offhand. (If anyone else does, please edit this answer to add it in!)

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the mistakes!